# Как переместить блок с рейтингом в верхнюю часть блока?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, шорткод

Есть [демо сайт](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/30/) на котором установлены плагины [Easy Testimonials](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-testimonials/installation/) для задания персонажей и плагин [WP-PostRatings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) для выставления рейтинга пользователями сайта. [На странице](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/30/972-2/) я вывел персонажей в виде сетки с помощью шорткода

```
[testimonials_grid theme="light_style" cols="3" responsive="1" equal_height_rows="1" testimonials_per_page="10" paginate="0" count="10" orderby="date" order="ASC" show_title="1" use_excerpt="1" show_thumbs="1" show_rating="stars"]
```

и в файле плагина рейтинга **easy-testimonials.php** заменил строку

```
$testimonial['rating'] = get_post_meta($postid, '_ikcf_rating', true);
```

на

```
$testimonial['rating'] = get_post_meta($postid, 'ratings_average', true);
```

подменив тем самым стандартный рейтинг плагина Easy Testimonials на доп. мета поле WP-PostRatings.
Теперь вопрос: как поместить рейтинг в верхнюю часть сразу после заголовка, когда [согласно](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-testimonials/installation/) свойства шорткода **show_rating=before** и **show_rating=stars** исключают друг друга? и можно ли как-то отсортировать выводимых персонажей не по дате, а рейтингу?